# External angle bisectors of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Exterior angle bisectors of the side $\triangle ABC$ at vertices $B$ and $C$ intersect at $D$. Find $\angle BDC$ if $\angle BAC=40^{\circ}$

I cannot visualize this problem... If I draw a triangle and bisect the exterior angles, they never meet at a common point. Is this some sort of typo?

Comment: Well, that or you're working in spherical geometry.

Comment: The angle bisectors are probably to be thought of as *lines* through $B$ and $C$, not *rays*.

Comment: @Blue though in that case there would be no meaningful distinction between external and internal: both describe the same line.

Comment: @DanUznanski: Internal angle bisector lines pass through the interior of the triangle; exterior angle bisector lines ---that is, lines bisecting the *exterior angles*--- do not. The interior bisector at a vertex is in fact perpendicular to the external bisector at that vertex. Definitely not the same line.

Comment: Oh, I see, it bisects the angle between the usual part of one edge and the extension of the other; for some reason I thought we were talking about both extensions.  Silly me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the following sketch can help.

[image]

Comment: I see so my picture was drawn with the rays pointing in the opposite direction. Wouldn't angle ACD be 90 if you're bi secting a line

Comment: @adam It would be better if you consider external bisectors as lines instead of rays.

Comment: So the key to solving this problem is to know that interior angle bisectors are prepindicular to external angle bisectors. So I just draw a interior angle bisector and that will be perpendicular to line AC. Will this work?

Comment: That will work. Another approach (it is simpler, I think) is, apply the combination of "angle sum of triangle" + "adjacent angles on a straight line".

Comment: Let's call $C=\angle ACB, B=\angle ABC$. Clearly $\angle CBD=90^o-B/2$ and $\angle BCD=90^o-C/2$ therefore $\angle CDB=(180^o-\angle CBD-\angle BCD)=(B+C)/2=(180-A)/2=140^o/2=70^o$ so I was not kidding for the one line answer.

Comment: @frank000 You are right and not kidding. But posting your comment (answer) under my post instead of yours is kidding. Just kidding...

Comment: @frankooo what is $\angle BCD$ complementary to???? I dont follow with that step

Comment: @adam on ray AC but outside segment AC, let's call it it X. $\angle ACB+\angle BCD+\angle DCX=180^o$, and $\angle BCD=\angle DCX$

Answer (score 1):

[image: Exterior angle bisectors]

The exterior angle bisectors are just orthogonal to the interior angle bisectors,
hence $$\widehat{BDC}=\pi-\widehat{BIC}=\frac{\widehat{ABC}+\widehat{ACB}}{2}=\frac{\pi-\widehat{BAC}}{2}.$$
This gives that if $\widehat{BAC}=40^\circ$, then $\widehat{BDC}=70^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

It cause you draw the bisector of the small sideways. for example if b>c. you must continue the AC for external angel. This problem came out of this equation: [image: Triangle Image]

> AB/AC = BE/EC